# Streaming audio and video AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have couple of videos that I'm streaming. I start with the `video_1.flv` and after it finishes the `video_2.flv` is running and looping until the user takes some action to play other movie for example `video_3.flv`. So I need when `video_2.flv` is playing in  the background to be played audio file `sound.mp3` witch is going to be looped , witch i managed to do. But I need both of them to run independently. Because right now when the video is looped the audio is looping to. And I need the audio to be playd only when `video_2.flv` is played. Thank YOU.

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
loader.vid.Video_1.attachNetStream(ns);



var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {};
ns.client = listener;

ns.play("http://media.easyads.bg/ads/display_ads_richmedia/video/avon/maria_ilieva/video_1.flv");
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, NCListener);

var clipTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000);

function NCListener(e:NetStatusEvent){

    if (e.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {

        ns.play("http://media.easyads.bg/ads/display_ads_richmedia/video/avon/maria_ilieva/video_2.flv");
        sound.load(req);
        shaker(null);
        }
};

    var sound:Sound = new Sound();
    var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sound.mp3");
    sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);

    function onSoundLoadComplete(e:Event):void{
        sound.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoadComplete);
        soundChannel = sound.play();
        soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
    }

    function onSoundChannelSoundComplete(e:Event):void{
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onSoundChannelSoundComplete);
        soundChannel = sound.play();
    }
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, play_video_01);
loader.button_01.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, play_effect_01);

function play_video_01 (event:MouseEvent){

    clipTimer.stop();
    ns.play("http://media.easyads.bg/ads/display_ads_richmedia/video/avon/maria_ilieva/video_3.flv");
    loader.button_01_mc.gotoAndPlay (41);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial is helpful to you...
I'm new in AS but I'd rather prefer to pack the whole s.... stuff into a (reusable) class...

[Behavior of a Loaded SWF File versus Behavior of a MovieClip](http://www.flashandmath.com/howtos/swfs/index.html)

Greets

Gee

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point but time you know... :-/  Will try to follow your idea.